# How to create gasless-transactions/meta-transaction using ethers.js?

Tags: ethereum, polygon, ethers.js

How can I implement a meta-transaction using **ethers.js** library or at least have **another account paying** a transaction, which was signed by different account?

Consider a transaction to transfer 100 ERC20-tokens using a ERC20-contract from `0xAccountA` to `0xAccountB`. The transaction will be signed by `0xAccountA` but the gas would be payed by some other `0xAccountC`.

Lets initiate a contract:

```
const abi = ['function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount)'];

const payer = new ethers.Wallet(privKey, provider);
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, payer);
```

Currently, we create transactions like this;

```
const contractWithFromAsSigner = contract.connect(from);
const tx = await contractWithFromAsSigner.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
```

In this case, `from` has to sign the transaction and is also paying for the transaction.

What I'd like to achieve is that `from` is signing this transaction, but `payer` is paying and really broadcasting the transaction, which was signed by `from`, but paid by `payer`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are roughly trying to describe a relayer manager. You can have it on-chain. Afaik there aren't many implementations but you can check these resources which have implemented it (EIP 1077) and modify it to your use case:

- https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1077.md#similar-implementations
- https://github.com/argentlabs/argent-contracts/blob/ea361609bbda15bf19bac35dbc2af80b720cb27b/contracts/modules/RelayerManager.sol

Your ethers.js would then call the `execute` fn of the relayer contract.